# Plot the indices of the background Matrix instead of the calculated values

Tags: plotting, matrix, indexing

I want to create a background 60*100 matrix and insert inside it the calculated values, for example

```
data = {{1, 60.51}, {2, 24.5115}, {3, 9.92919}, {4, 4.02214}, {5, 1.6293}, {6, 0.66}}
```

The rest elements of the matrix are zeros. Then instead of plotting data I want to plot their corresponding indices in the matrix. The result should look like this:

[image: Like the photo]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for here. Could you give some more detail about what you need? Preferably a minimal example of the input and desired output?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit thanks! I updated the question by adding a photo as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array = Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, {8, 5}];
{checkmark, dot} = {"✓", "\[FilledSmallCircle]"};

labeledcells = Join[Thread[{1, Range[5]}], {{2, 1}, {8, 1}}];
markedcells = {{2, 2}, {4, 3}, {6, 5}};
dottedcells = Complement[Tuples[{Range[8], Range[5]}], labeledcells, markedcells];

array2 = ReplacePart[array, {markedcells :> checkmark, dottedcells :> dot}];

MatrixForm[array2]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[array2 /. {dot -> White, checkmark -> Green, _Subscript -> Red}, 
 Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 16, Black], #2 - .5] &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose @ array2, {2}]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks! How to over-plot the x and y axes with ticks?

Comment: @Shaaban, just add the options `Frame -> True` and `FrameTicks -> Automatic`.